# ExpandableListView problems

Tags: android, android-layout, expandablelistview

I'm trying to create an expandable list where I can make the height of the group_row smaller, to use less screen space.  When I change the layout_height of the LinearLayout, it changes the height to what I want it, but all of the labels of each TextView aren't displayed; they disappear.  However, when it is wrap_content, the text appears.  Any ideas how to fix?

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:orientation="horizontal"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="35dp">

<TextView android:id="@+id/childname
        android:paddingLeft="0dp"
        android:textSize="16dp"
        android:textStyle="italic"
        android:layout_width="150dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content">
    </TextView>

</LinearLayout>
```

Answer (score 0):

Textview id should be android:id="@+id/childname"